# how to access to issued token for anothr user in IdentityServer 4.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I want to sign out another user as admin forcibly, and I am trying to do that by using Revoke API, but in this case, I have just username and Revoke Api need issued tokens (access and refresh), how can I find these tokens?

Comment: If using username can get other user's tocken,it will not be safe.So it may be hard to do.

Comment: I know that data that token is composed of them are stored in PesistedGrants table but I cannot find a way to rebuild the token.